# Base conversion between base r^3 to r^2

Tags: computer-science

The problem asks the following:

> If $(\alpha2)_{r^3} = (r3\beta)_{r^2},$ find $\alpha, \beta,$ and r.

First off, I assume $r^2$ > 3 and $r^3 > 2$.

I know that $(r3\beta)_{r^2}$ = (10 _ _ _ _ )$_{r}$

I've attempted to convert to base 10 and set them equal to each other:

> $(\alpha2)_{r^3} = \alpha ({r^3})^1 + 2({r^3})^0 $
>                     = $ (\alpha {r^3} + 2)_{10}$
>
> $(r3\beta)_{r^2} = r({r^2})^2 + 3({r^2})^1 + \beta ({r^2})^0 = (r({r^4}) + 3{r^2} + \beta)_{10}$

and converting to base r:

> $\alpha = Mr^2 + Nr + O$
>
> $ 2 = Xr^2 + Y$
>
> $ r = 1r + 0$
>
> $ 3 = Sr + T$
>
> $ \beta = Vr + U$

But I'm pretty much stuck at this point. Don't see any logical progression from here (if I'm even headed in the right direction).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= Ar^2 + Br + C \\
2 &= Dr^2 + Er + F \\
3 &= Gr + H \\
\beta &= Ir + J
\end{align*}
where each uppercase coefficient is some integer in $\{0, 1, \ldots, r - 1\}$. Then by substituting into our expressions in base $10$, we have that:
$$
(Ar^2 + Br + C)r^3 + (Dr^2 + Er + F) = r^5 + (Gr + H)r^2 + (Ir + J)
$$
Comparing coefficients, we have:
\begin{align*}
\boxed{r^5}:\quad A &= 1 \\
\boxed{r^4}:\quad B &= 0 \\
\boxed{r^3}:\quad C &= G \\
\boxed{r^2}:\quad D &= H \\
\boxed{r^1}:\quad E &= I \\
\boxed{r^0}:\quad F &= J \\
\end{align*}
Now let's assume that $r \geq 2$. Then $2 \geq Dr^2 \geq 4D$, which implies that $D = 0$. Hence, $H = 0$ so that $3 = Gr$. But then since $3$ is prime and $r \neq 1$, we have that $G = 1$ and $r = 3$.

Now since $G = 1$, we know that $C = 1$ so that $\alpha = 1(3)^2 + 0(3) + 1 = 10$.

Likewise, since $r = 3$, we know that $D = E = H = I = 0$ and $F = J = 2$ so that $\beta = 0(3) + 2 = 2$.